# Different modules using subdir links with a global layout?

Tags: zend-framework

I need a modular design for new version of my web application project which I'm planning to design like this:

foo.com/baz ---> baz module

foo.com/bar ---> bar module

foo.com/admin ---> admin module
and so on...

I'm asked to design it with a single layout which will have a navigation on top and that will change the highlighted link for active module. But for admin module, I need a different layout. Also, all these modules will use static files, like images, js, and css files from a foo.com/static folder.

Is there a quick and appropriate way to design this structure without using URL routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use your example routing by default. Check out the [docs on modules](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.modules). You should be able to use a module bootstrap to change the layout for your admin module:

```
$this->getResource('layout')->setLayout('admin');
```

You may even be able to use a module specific configuration (not certian about this):

```
resources.layout.layout = "layout" 
admin.resources.layout.layout = "admin"
```

Highlighting the link of the active page is pretty trivial:

```
<?php $active = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getModuleName();?>
<div>
  <?php foreach($modules as $module => $display): ?>
    <span class='tab<?if($module == $active):?> highlight<?php endif; >?'>
      <a href='<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => $module))?>'>
        <?php echo $display; ?>
      </a>
    </span>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Or you could use [`Zend_Navigation`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.html), which allows generating navigation based on modules/controllers/actions.